# What's the appropriate word for describing "potential client"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I want to replace a phrase "this client will eventually bring a great profit for our company" with a shorter one, but I don't know what word I should use in this scenario. I'm currently using "potential client", but it sounded a little odd to me. Any ideas?

Comment: Is this term to be used to their face, or internally with other employees of your company?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Prospect** and **prospective client** are commonly used in sales, which sounds appropriate for your situation.

Answer (score 2):

A *lead* can also be used.  It is actually frequently used in the marketing area.

Comment: But you wouldn't call someone a "lead" to their face - it has a very unflattering implication (and reminds me of Glengarry Glen Ross).